# Upload zip (custom gradle wrapper) to artifactory via gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

i want to upload my custom gradle wrapper to artifactory.
I tried:

1. standard upload task from gradle 'base' plugin
2. artifactory gradle plugin

I always have some layout like /group/name/revision/[name]-[revision].zip
What i need is simple `repo/name-revision.zip`, like in gradle-distribution repository: https://services.gradle.org/distributions

I am trying to upload zip into gradle-local pregenerated artifactory repo with 'Gradle' layout

I read about ivy layouts etc, but it all seems over complicated for such simple task.

Any advice?

Comment: Have you thought about using a FTP server ?

Comment: It's just completely ok to stick with artifactory here. It's enterprise standard for artifact distribution in company, and we have no need to add additional entities in this scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Using gradle-3.1 this works for me:

`gradle.properties`

```
artifactory = http://yourserver/artifactory/reponame
artifactoryUser = username
artifactoryPassword = the-encryped-password
```

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'distribution'

group = 'foo.bar'
version = '0.5-SNAPSHOT'

// not needed since we have standard layout src/main/dist
// distributions { main { contents { from { ... } } } }

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: artifactory) {
                authentication(userName: artifactoryUser, password: artifactoryPassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(url: artifactory) {
                authentication(userName: artifactoryUser, password: artifactoryPassword)
            }
        }
    }
}

$> tree src
src
└── main
    └── dist
        ├── bla.txt
        └── blub.txt

$> ./gradlew uploadArchives
:distTar
:distZip
:uploadArchives

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.332 secs
```

The zip can then be found in artifactory